# How to delete data based on the params url selected on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models on rails with following associations:

```
class Manufacturer 
  has_many :equipments
end

class Equipments
  belongs_to :manufacturer
end
```

I have an `Equipments` show page with following fields:

```
title,                     
category_id,               
sub_category_id,           
manufacturer_id
```

When I am on the equipment `show` page

I am trying to give a button which when clicked will fetch the `manufacturer_id` on that page based on the `equipment_id` on the `url` and delete it from the record of the `Manufacturer` table.
I know how to do it from `Manufacturer` `show` page. It will be like:

`Manufacturer.find(params[:manufacturer_id])`.

But how can I do it same from the Equipment show page ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. The 'correct' way would be having a link in your equipment show page that makes a delete request to the `ManufacturersController#destroy` action, sending the `@equipment.manufacturer_id` as a parameter. Like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Manufacturer', manufacturer_path(@equipment.manufacturer_id), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Some confirmation message'} %>
```

This will send the `manufacturer_id` as the param `id`. This also assumes that you have in your `routes.rb` something like:

```
resources :manufacturers
```

Then, in your `manufacturers_controller.rb`:

```
def destroy:
    @manufacturer = Manufacturer.find(params[:id])
    @manufacturer.destroy
    redirect_to some_place, notice: 'Manufacturer successfully deleted'
end
```

Aditionaly, if you have only the `equipment_id` and want to retrieve the associated `Manufacturer`, you can do something like this:

```
@manufacturer = Manufacturer.joins(:equipments).where(equipments: {id: params[:equipment_id]}).first
@manufacturer.destroy if @manufacturer.present?
```

Answer (score 0):

In equipment show page:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', delete_manufacturer_equipment_path(@equipment.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

In equipments controller:

```
   def delete_manufacturer
     @manufacturer = Manufacturer.joins(:equipments).where(equipments: {id: params[:id]}).first
     @manufacturer.destroy if @manufacturer.present?
    redirect_to :back, notice: 'Manufacturer successfully deleted'
  end
```

In routes

```
 resources :equipments do
   member do
     delete :delete_manufacturer
   end
 end
```